# Can the toolshelf be moved to the top/bottom

Tags: interface, accessibility

Problem:  the vertical orientation of the toolshelf makes it next to impossible to read the labels.  I can't find a way to drag-and-reorient it, nor do there seem to be any relevant settings.

Solutions:

1. tilt my head ->  Owing to physical limitations I can't tilt my head far enough to read them.
2. horizontal orientation (top/bottom of view pane) - doesn't seem to be possible
3. rotate the labels - doesn't seem to be a way to do this

As far as #3 goes, I did a custom build where I literally just hardcoded the toolshelf tab-width (height) and the label text orientation.  It was ugly because I don't understand enough about the Blender ecosystem to write code to do this that's not ugly.

Am I missing some non-obvious-to-me UI affordance for moving the toolshelf, or is there a setting (even a hidden one in a style-definition) where this could be specified?

Comment: Python API allows you to code new interface elements with scripting to a certain extent without having to compile custom builds, though I'm not sure you can create new create shelves. Blender 4.0 plans to add a new type of asset self that runs along the bottom of the 3D view, maybe the groundwork introduced will facilitate extending it with addons later.